# Accessing a bit array in linked list node

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a linked list defined as such:

```
typdef struct _seg
{
    int bits[256];        // # of bits in bits[] array = 256

    struct _seg *next;    // link to the next segment
} seg;
```

And I was wondering how I can access the bit array inside each node of this list. If it were a regular `int` variable and the list was called `p`, I could just do `p->bits = 13;`. But I don't know how to get to and modify the list in this case. Can someone please help me out?

P.S. (not as important) Does anyone know what the `seg;` does at the very end?

Comment: Here you find the meaning of "typedef": http://stackoverflow.com/a/612350/126125

Comment: @Markon Thanks! That makes a lot of sense and makes things a lot easier!

Comment: The way you've declared your structure, the `bits` array is an array of ints, so it has `256*sizeof(int)*8` bits.

Answer (score 1):

`p->bits` is an array of 256 integers.  You can access it with `p->bits[0] = 13`.

Or in general `p->bits[i] = 13` where `0 <= i < 256`.

> typdef struct _seg 
>   {
>    ...
>   }seg;

With this you can define a variable of this struct type using `seg` as

```
seg SomeName;
```

No need for `struct _seg someName;`.

Comment: I'm assuming you meant to type `p->bits[0] = 13`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To access the nodes in your list, you'll have to use a loop to iterate on all your elements:

```
seg* p = createList();

seg* current = p; // start at first element
while( current != NULL ){
    for( int i=0; i<256; i++ ) {
        current->bits[i] = 13;  // modify bits inside
    }
    current = current->next; // go to next element in the list
}
```